# compare 2 time series and remove intercept values

Tags: time-series, compare

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgoNX.png)

I have two time series, and I need to compare them and remove the values from second column when first column has any values. so I want 2017-01-02 06:00:00 row to be out, and i have more situations like that.

Comment: Hard to see what is really the question?

Comment: thanks Chris, i solved it already :)